# Sound Synthesis from object collision in Virtual Reality Environment

Tags: c++, physics-engine, sound-synthesis, virtual-reality

I have a project whose subject is "Sound Synthesis from object collision in Virtual Reality Environment"
First of all, I have to define some objects with certain attributes (like shape, mass, material) and then I have to create sound from the collision of these objects in C++ according to their attributes, area of collision etc.
I think I have to use some sort of Physics Engine like Bullet or ODE but I'm not sure how to start this project. Is there any Physics Engine specialized in Sound Synthesis?

I've come up with PhyA but I don't know how to download it and implement it.
http://www.tech.dmu.ac.uk/~dylan/z/phya/

P.S.
I intend to use CHAI3d or H3dApi because I have to use the Falcon device.

Thank you in advance